# include strange behaviour with relative path

Tags: php

In my php project I try to include another file. However, I find it very confusing how the include statement works.

e.g.
I include the file HelperFile.php in index.php. Both files are in the same directory.

This works: `include 'HelperFile.php'` but this doesn't `include '/HelpferFile.php'` & `include './HelpferFile.php'`

The warning I receive:

> PHP Warning include(/HelperFile.php): failed to open stream

Out of curiosity I created a folder and moved my file HelperFile.php into it and nothing changed. Everytime I tried to use the relative path with `./`, `../` or `/`I received a warning.

Can someone explain me what's going on. I'm still learning and can'f figure out what's happening right now.

Comment: `/` is no relative path. Maybe watch your filenames? `/HelpferFile.php` vs. `HelperFile.php` `include './HelpferFile.php'` should work if you use the correct filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP isn't so great with relative paths, it generally prefers absolute paths. The easiest way around this is to use the **DIR** magic constant which returns the current directory of the file you're currently in.

So, for instance, you can do `include(__DIR__ . '/HelperFile.php');` which would be in the current directory.

However say you had a file in a folder up you can do
`include(__DIR__ . '/../MyOtherFile.php');`

Answer (score 0):

[PHP Doc says](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php#function.include)

> If a path is defined — whether absolute (starting with a drive letter
>   or \ on Windows, or / on Unix/Linux systems) or relative to the
>   current directory (starting with . or ..) — the include_path will be
>   ignored altogether. For example, if a filename begins with ../, the
>   parser will look in the parent directory to find the requested file.

If you use `.` or `..` will ignored for relative path Also use `../` for parent directory.